# Why is "sum A" not the same as "sum(A)" in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Why is it that `sum A` is not the same as `sum(A)` in MATLAB?

```
>> A

A =

     1     2
     3     4

>> sum A

ans =

    65

>> sum(A)

ans =

     4     6
```

A more general question would be: why is `sum A` working at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you call a function like

```
sum A
```

Matlab interprets the second as a string and passes it as the first argument to the function like:

```
sum('A')
```

And the output 65 comes from 65 being the integer representation of 'A'

This is quite neat with the large number of functions taking strings as input, like `cd`
Instead of

```
cd('somedirectory/')
```

you can write

```
cd somedirectory/
```

This is referred command syntax and functions called like this cannot have outputs

Here is a link with some additional details: (http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html)

Comment: Very interesting!  I think its worth point out that that it doesn't matter what A is, sum A returns the ASCII value of the character A, no matter any previous assignments.  Also, you can't assign this value directly to some other variable, e.g., try: b = sum A; which gives the error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.

Comment: Exactly, the simplified "command syntax" (the one wrapping ones input with quotes, making it a string) does in contrast to the standard "function syntax" not allow outputs.